# How can I add an App Registration key with PowerShell without breaking the Azure Portal?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I'm trying to automate the registration of Azure AD apps. However, it looks that managing Azure app registration keys with the Azure Portal and with the AzureAD PowerShell module is incompatible. Here is what I am doing:

- In the Azure Portal, register a new application
- In the Azure Portal, add some keys in the application, including one key named `AzurePortalKey`
  => I can add and remove keys without a problem
- In the AzureAD Powershell module (I've tried both the latest version 2.0.0.131 and the preview version), add a key to the application with the following command
  `New-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential -ObjectId <object id here> -CustomKeyIdentifier "PowerShellKey"`
- The key appears in the Azure Portal as expected (there is a delay of 10-20 seconds until the key is displayed in the Azure Portal)
- In the Azure Portal, try to add or remove some other keys
  => **These operations fail with an error message**:

  > Failed to update application test-bug keys.
  >   Error detail: Unable to complete the request due to data validation error.
- In the Azure Portal, remove the key `PowerShellKey` (either with the key management screen or in the manifest file)
  => Managing keys in the Azure Portal works again

The problem might be due to different encodings of the CustomKeyIdentifier used by Powershell and the Azure Portal:

- The CustomKeyIdentifier `PowerShellKey` is retrieved as `80, 111, 119, 101, 114, 83, 104, 101, 108, 108, 75, 101, 121` (likely UTF-8 or some other 8-bits encoding)
- The CustomKeyIdentifier `AzurePortalKey` is retrieved as `65, 0, 122, 0, 117, 0, 114, 0, 101, 0, 80, 0, 111, 0, 114, 0, 116, 0, 97, 0, 108, 0, 75, 0, 101, 0, 121, 0` (note the intermediary 0's, likely UTF-16 or some other 16-bits encoding)

Is there a way to manage keys with PowerShell without breaking the Azure Portal ?

**Edit**

Since it looks like a bug I've filed a [suggestion](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/32178868-fixing-new-azureadapplicationpasswordcredential) in the Microsoft Azure feedback forums. Please upvote it if fixing this problem is important for you !

Answer (score 1):

1. If you just  want to **remove** other keys which added from portal:

You can manage keys through **Manifest.**

Go to Azure  portal > You Application > Manifest > Find and select the Key you want to remove > Delete it and save manifest.

Then you can success remove the Key. 
[image]

2. If you want to **add** keys from portal after adding keys from Powershell:

As you considered, two different keys have different `customKeyIdentifier` format. So, you **should not apply** `customKeyIdentifier` in Powershell.

You can just use `New-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential -ObjectId 53f6e6ea-xxxx-4ebe-xxxx-8309dad5003d`  to add keys from powershell.

This key's `customKeyIdentifier` in Manifest is `null`.  You can see the key in portal which has Description with `Key description` .

Then you can add or remove keys from portal or powershell without breaking.

The following picture shows that I had added keys from portal after adding a key from Powershell.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can confirm that using `New-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential` with no `CustomKeyIdentifier` doesn't break the Azure portal. However I need to provision keys with a `CustomKeyIdentifier` with Powershell.

Comment: Hi, @LMC .Unfortunately, I think it impossible to do that. This is caused by design. I did a test  and found that it cannot  achieve that. If this is very important to you, you can post your idea in this Feedback Forum: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory   Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi @wayne-yang-msft, I think this should rather be considered a bug. Where could I file a bug ?

Comment: You can always send a quick tweet: https://twitter.com/Azure

or post on Azure MSDN Forum:
https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/forums/

Comment: Hi,@LMC . If this answer is helpful to you, pleas mark it as answer , so that we can help more communities. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @wayne-yang-msft. I appreciate your answer but it doesn't say how I can manage keys with a `CustomKeyIdentifier` (which I think is the normal case and the case I'm looking for). However I upvoted your answer. Also, disagree that a PowerShell command can break the Azure Portal by design. If you edit your answer and clearly state it's not possible for now because of a bug I will mark it as answer.

Comment: HI, @ LMC , Sorry for my unclear answer.  I will follow this issue further. I'm not sure whether it is a bug. I will report this issue and contact Azure Team. If I have any process , I will keep you updated.

Comment: Hi @wayne-yang-msft, thanks a lot for your time and help. As stated in the "edit" of my answer,  I've filed a [suggestion](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/32178868-fixing-new-azureadapplicationpasswordcredential) in the Microsoft Azure feedback forums. However it would be better to be able to report a bug (and not a suggestion) as we can do for example with the SharePoint Framework (here is an [example](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/914)).